# Assistance with read access violation when using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

After trying to use the draw_cards_from_deck function after the player's turn happens, I get a read access violation and I don't know why.

The main block of code is here: 
    https://pastebin.com/kQi75h5F

And the header: 
https://pastebin.com/tAbDmyFY

```
struct Deck {
int* cards; //an array of cards 
int deck_size;  //the size of the deck
int* cnt_top;   //the index to the top card;
};
```

Comment: As-is your code is not a [mcve]. Please post the relevant code as code, not as links, take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: `a=b` assigns the value of `b` to `a`. `a==b` tests `a` and `b` for equality.

Comment: Check the return values when reading data from the user to ensure you got valid inputs before using the inputs.

Comment: @user4581301 these suggestions are not relevant to the problem i'm having

Comment: How do you know that? When I fed in inputs like "fubar" and "balderdash", the program segfaulted. If you want people to find the same bug, you need to supply code and the inputs used to expose the bug. Without those best I can do is guess.